# How do I convert a "subset" into slices/tensor/matrix that I obtained using "torch.utils.data.random_split()" in PyTorch?

Tags: pandas, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to divide my data into training and testing datasets in PyTorch using torch.utils.data.random_split().

```
train, test = torch.utils.data.random_split(iris, [112, 38], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(42))
```

The output for the train and set sets from the code above is:
<torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset at 0x141a7379b50>

I'm trying to assign the values below to my training and test sets using the code below, although I'm getting: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" error.

```
train_X = train[['Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length',
                 'Petal.Width']]
train_y = train.Species

test_X = test[['Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length',
                 'Petal.Width']]
test_y = test.Species
```

I looked through multiple posts on stackoverflow but couldn't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following extremely hacky solution:

```
test = torch.stack([t for t in test])
```

Where `test` is now a tensor of length 38.
When you call:

```
train, test = torch.utils.data.random_split(iris, [112, 38], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(42))
```

Then `train` and `test` are Subsets (as you noted), which are kind of fancy generators. You can evaluate the generator with the list comprehension.
This is not good coding, but it works in a pinch.

Comment: I see the reasoning behind, so smart nice!